# how can i make my function inverse in r?

Tags: r

This is my function `pchi <- function(x,df)`. i want to make it inverse with respect to x. this is my code:

```
pchi <- function(x,df)
{

 integrand<-function(x){(1/(2^(df/2)*(gamma(df/2))))*((x^((df/2)-1))*exp(-1*(x/2)))}
ans <- integrate(integrand,lower=0,upper=x)
return(ans)
}
```

what is the process to make it inverse?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `pchi` outcome to `return(ans$value)`, then following gives an inverse

```
qchi = function (y, df) {
    uniroot(function (x) pchi(x, df) - y, lower = 0, upper = 10)$root
}

> qchi(0.8,4)
[1] 5.988608

> qchisq(0.8, 4)
[1] 5.988617
```

Not exactly the same, but close enough. Aside from learning purposes, you always should use `qchisq`.

Answer (score 4):

Since you have replicated the `pchisq()` function from base R, you can use the built-in `qchisq()` function:

```
pchi(5,4)
## 0.7127025 with absolute error < 7.9e-15
pchisq(5,4)
## [1] 0.7127025
qchisq(0.7127025,4)
## [1] 5
```

Comment: you are right. but I want to code it without using direct command like qchisq(). is there any way?

Comment: you could use `uniroot()`.  Why do you want to do it the hard way?

Comment: I tried `uniroot()` but can't code properly. basically i am new in r.